# tsc: not found at heroku when I upload the React+next js and node project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js

I have react+next and node js project and I want to deploy that project at heroku. That is the structure of my project:- [image]

and my package.json file is [image]
if I add "Start": "next start" only the frontend works and if I changed it  "Start": "tsc -p server/tsconfig.json -watch &&  node server.js" it's gave me the error.

error is :-[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Heroku installs the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` listed in `package.json`, all `devDependencies` get removed before the `npm start` command is run. So if you installed `typescript` under `devDependencies` and your project needs it at runtime, it won't be found. To stop it from being pruned, move `typescript` over to `dependencies` instead.

Another option would be to skip the pruning process altogether by setting the following config vars:

```sh
$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

Or set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to anything other than `production` (Heroku's default).

Comment: I added same thing and that is my "start":"tsc -p server/tsconfig.json -watch && node server.js " command now its showing "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60" and in server.js I am using that code
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || '3008';
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});

Comment: @Mangita What happens if you manually include the host after `PORT`, e.g., `app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => { console.log(` ... ?

Comment: same error when I tried this const port = process.env.PORT || '3008';
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Server is running s on port: ' + port)
});

Comment: @Mangita I think we'll need a little more information about your project. Are there other parts of your stack that require connecting to a port (e.g., PostgreSQL) that could be causing that error? Are you building some type of browser-based TypeScript editor? I ask that because `tsc` in `-watch` mode is typically used only during development (i.e., only compiled JS is uploaded to or used in production). If not, then your `start` script should look like `"start": "node server.js"` because `build` already generated your JS.

Comment: my project is react+next and for backend, I am using node js for running backend code I am using these two commands at my local 1. tsc -p  server/tsconfig.json -watch 2. node server.js.  This command creates a  convert the  .ts file to .js  files for production I added these two commands into one line like this  "start": "tsc -p server/tsconfig.json && node server.js",

Comment: may be this is wrong I h am not sure its right or not "start": "tsc -p server/tsconfig.json && node server.js",

Comment: @Mangita In that case, I would create two separate scripts: `"start": "node server.js"` for production (this is what Heroku will use) and `"dev": "tsc -p server/tsconfig.json -watch && node server.js"` for development (this is what you would use only on your machine). The `heroku-postbuild` you already have up there handles compiling to JS during deployment for you.

Comment: I tried the same thing which you told me like this "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
    },its give me error my usercontroller.js not found which should be created automatically according to your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244698/discussion-between-mark-g-and-mangita).